# counting the percentage that a category represents

Tags: python, pandas

i'm sorry first for the title i'm not used to communicate with english but i'm going to explain my problem
i have 2 categorical variable the first one represents the damage grade it takes 3 values 1-2-3
the second one represents the number of floors.

first i did a groupy of the 2 variable and a value counts the result was like that

```
damage            number floors
1                        2         12593
                         1          8969
                         3          2537
2                        2          93968
                         3          28479 
                         1          20798
```

number of floors takes from 1 to 9 i didnt write everything
and i counted the sum of each number of floor

```
1  40441
2  156623
3   55617
```

my idea is to have a table like this

```
damage   number floors    percentage
1              2          (12593/156623)*100
               1          (8969/40441)*100
               3          (2537/55617)*100
```

and if you have any proposition of a nice plot to use to translate this table 
i will be grateful .

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#possible solution for count
#s = df.groupby(['damage','number floors']).size()
print (s)
  damage  number floors
1       2                12593
        1                 8969
        3                 2537
2       2                93968
        3                28479
        1                20798
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

For `sum` by second level of `MultiIndex` use:

```
print (s.sum(level=1))
number floors
2    106561
1     29767
3     31016
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Then divide by second level with [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) and multiple by `100`:

```
s = s.div(s.sum(level=1), level=1).mul(100)
print (s)
damage  number floors
1       2                11.817644
        1                30.130682
        3                 8.179649
2       2                88.182356
        3                91.820351
        1                69.869318
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

And for reshape use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = s.unstack()
print (df1)
number floors          1          2          3
damage                                        
1              30.130682  11.817644   8.179649
2              69.869318  88.182356  91.820351
```

So you can plot by [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df1.plot.bar()
```

Comment: thank you so much , your answer is exactly what i'm looking for